# PHP: File upload always returning nothing

Tags: php

Hey guys I'm working on a file uploader and I have come across a problem. In my code I am checking to see if a file has been selected via the file upload form, here is the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="actions/save.php?id=<?print($id);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Listing Photo: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input class="add" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

The user selects the file to upload then clicks the "Save" button. Now in my uploading code i am trying to check if the file form has been set like this:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];    
if(isset($file)) {
//Continue

} else {
//Go back    

}
```

Now my problem is that even if the file input is set (File selected) it goes to the "Go back" part of the code.

Any suggestions or a different way of checking?

Any help is appreciate, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you upload files through form, you should have $_FILES superglobal array with that file, so try

```
print_r($_FILES['file'])
```

to see what it cointains (size, error code, path ...)

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files end up in `$_FILES`, not in `$_POST`

see: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php for documentation and examples

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to uploaded files using the `$_FILES` array. See also the [reference documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).